# How to change name of a list in python according to function arguments

Tags: python

Suppose we have a function

```
def analyse(n):
      for c in cluster_{n}:
             do something
```

For example if we run `analyse(1)` I want it to run like

```
for c in cluster_1 :
         do something
```

where `cluster_1` is a global list already declared.

How can I do that?

Comment: Just *pass the list as an argument*. Don't dynamically access global variables.

Comment: but how can we do it if i want multiple lists without passing all those arguments

Comment: Use a list of lists.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but top thinking in terms of *variables* think in terms of objects. What *object/data structure* do you need for your problem?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga lists would be fine

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you can pass the list as argument directly.

Another way to do so is to create a dictionary and store all the global lists in it, like this;

```
obj = {"cluster_1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}

def analyse(n):
      for c in obj[f'cluster_{n}']:
             print(c)


analyse(1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```